Redis cluster is identified as down
I have a dotnet application that uses a redis cluster for caching. Recently I came across an issue where the dotnet application identifies as the cluster has gone down. but when checked with the cluster info command the cluster status is intact.
Any ideas what might have caused this issue?
TIA
--UPDATE--


What exactly do you see in the application? does something like SET or GET work on the server? If you're seeing -CLUSTERDOWN responses: that comes from the server itself, so there's not much the application can do. Is it possible that it was down but has since repaired?

Yes it started working after I reinstated the cluster after flushing and clearing everything. I have added a screenshot in the logs that i got from the application

Sometimes Redis clusters changes its configurations due to failover stuff  (when you use Sentinel), it is better to instruct your code to get new config from cluster whenever its connectivity is down.

to be fair, the library should do that; however, CLUSTERDOWN comes from the server, which means that the node being communicated with had disabled things and was refusing to process commands; your application literally cannot compensate for that - the cluster itself needs to be happy

From the log, this looks like a legitimate panic at the cluster; CLUSTERDOWN isn't generated by the client library or your application, but rather: by the redis node that was being communicated with. This strongly suggests some major blip in the internal redis server state, which needs to be recovered before commands can be processed. This recovery could be automatic (most likely in the case of a temporary network blip) or manual (most likely in the case of critical failure potentially impacting all redundant nodes in a vertical, or at least the primary before failover election can occur).
If the library failed to recover after the cluster had repaired itself, then that sounds like a potential topic for the library to investigate, but note that such recovery can never be instantaneous: when things are this ill, all the library can do is periodic polling to see if things have recovered - constantly hammering the servers with "are you happy yet? are you happy yet? are you happy yet?" would be detrimental to the cluster.

I think this could have happened as I have everything deployed across a multi node Kubernetes cluster. Ill check if there have been any network issues between the two worker nodes
